# Semantic UI popup fluid tag not working inside of ui item class

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a Popup Menu, much like the example in the [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#popup-menu), but the `fluid` attribute stops working if I wrap the popup in a `ui item` class as well as a menu class. Instead the popup just appears as wide as the button.

I need the `ui item` class in order to keep my my menu elements lined up properly, so I'm looking for a work around in order to keep the fluid attribute (or get an equivalent effect) with both the menu and item classes in place.

My code looks a bit like this (with some additional elements mixed in, but this code is sufficient to replicate the error):

```
<div class="ui menu">
<!-- Removing ether menu above, or item below will cause the fluid tag to work -->
  <div class="ui item">

    <div class="ui button">
      hi
    </div>
    <div class="ui fluid popup">
    <!-- fluid class currently has no effect -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hb54c7r0/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fluid is taking on the width of the item container, as explained to me here:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5029

The solution is to declare the popup outside of the item and explicitly point to it rather than using `inline`.